# Django URL namespaces - the template has to know its namespace?

Tags: django, url, namespaces

I've been tinkering with (my first) Django project that started out with Django 1.6 and has just recently moved to Django 1.8. I've also been working through Django Patterns & Best Practices, learning how I should have structured it all along :-)

My project has several sub-apps and a typical main urls.py with lines like:

```
 (r'', include('noc.apps.frontpage.urls')),
```

Within each app, I've prefixed all the URL names with the app name, e.g. frontpage_edit_page and used `{% url %}` throughout the templates to refer between views.

Then I read about URL namespaces, and thought I could de-uglify my URL names. As I first interpreted it, if I added a namespace to each include() in the main urls.py, everything would function as before, because the URL names referred to would all be resolved by the 'local' app. But it doesn't seem to work that way.

With this in the main urls.py:

```
(r'', include('noc.apps.frontpage.urls', namespace='frontpage', app_name='frontpage')),
```

This in the app urls.py:

```
 url(r'^frontpage/edit/(?P<slug>[A-Za-z0-9]+)$', views.edit_page, name='front_page_edit_page'),
```

and `{% url 'front_page_edit_page' slug=page.slug %}` in a template inside that app, I get a NoReverseMatch exception with 0 URLs tried.

All the examples I can find are talking about prefixing URLs with the namespace - `frontpage:front_page_edit_page` but 1) how is this an improvement on the previous app prefix on the URL name? and 2) how could you ever have two instances of the same app, which is supposed to be a benefit... So I'm assuming that this is for linking *between* apps, not *within* apps.

So what is it that I am missing? Do I need to embed the app_name or namespace in my view function too? It's true that if I do prefix all my URL names with the namespace, even within the app, I get a rendered page, but it seems to defeat the point.

Comment: namespacing is so that you can have views with the same url name (eg "index", "create", "thank_you" etc) in different apps ...you could try to make unique names as the app author, by making them longer and prefixed with your app name, but you have no guarantee you made a unique name ...with namespaces the developer can ensure url names are unique across apps within their project

Comment: @Anentropic - that's what I understood too, but so far that's not what is actually happening, hence the question!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way you're meant to do it is indeed to add the namespace to the URL tag;

```
{% url 'frontpage:edit_page' slug='SLUG' %}
```

But it would be better practice to structure your main project URls file like this;

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),  # NOQA
    url(r'frontpage', include('noc.apps.frontpage.urls', namespace='frontpage', app_name='frontpage')),
```

That way you can specify the path for each app in the main URLs file, and avoid repetition;

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    'noc.apps.frontpage.views',
    url(r'^edit/(?P<slug>[A-Za-z0-9]+)$', 'edit_page', name='edit_page'),
```

With this you can introduce a [RESTful](http://blog.2partsmagic.com/restful-uri-design/) URL structure to all your apps so you'll end up with things like;

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),  # NOQA
    url(r'frontpage/', include('noc.apps.frontpage.urls', namespace='frontpage', app_name='frontpage')),
    url(r'contact/', include('noc.apps.contact.urls', namespace='contact', app_name='contact')),
    url(r'myapp/', include('noc.apps.myapp.urls', namespace='myapp', app_name='myapp')),
```

All your apps can follow a similar structure then;

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    'noc.apps.contact.views',
    url(r'^$', 'index', name='index'),
    url(r'^add/$', 'add', name='add'),
    url(r'^edit/(?P<slug>[A-Za-z0-9]+)$', 'edit', name='edit'),

urlpatterns = patterns(
    'noc.apps.myapp.views',
    url(r'^$', 'index', name='index'),
    url(r'^add/$', 'add', name='add'),
    url(r'^edit/(?P<slug>[A-Za-z0-9]+)$', 'edit', name='edit'),
```

Multiple instances of `frontpage` could be achieved using the top level namespace;

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),  # NOQA
    url(r'frontpage/', include('noc.apps.frontpage.urls', namespace='frontpage1', app_name='frontpage')),
    url(r'frontpage/', include('noc.apps.frontpage.urls', namespace='frontpage2', app_name='frontpage')),
```

That way you should be able to target the top level instance namespace, followed by the app namespace like this;

```
{% url 'frontpage1:frontpage:edit_page' slug='SLUG' %}
{% url 'frontpage2:frontpage:edit_page' slug='SLUG' %}
```

But if you would like to keep your template links more generic I believe you can leave out the top level namespace and django will resolve to the current app which you have to add to the request object. This is detailed at the end of [Reversing Namespaced URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls)

Comment: Maybe I was unclear, but that's exactly what I did. The only thing I haven't done yet is actually simplify the names, because I can't get it to work with the original names. 

So with the namespace hardcoded into the template, how can you possibly use the same app twice, which is the example in the Django manual? (two instances of a poll app) And why is it any better than just putting 'appname_' on the front of all your url names?

More to the point, I guess - do you specify the namespace prefix on url tags, even within the same app?

Comment: You hard-code the `app_name` (which is the same for both instances of the app), but the `namespace` should be different for both instances. You then pass the current namespace as the `current_app` argument, and the hard-coded `app_name` will resolve to the current `namespace`.

Comment: "You then pass the current namespace as the current_app argument" - aha, I think this is what I'm missing. Pass it to *what*? The requestcontext? And where does the app find what namespace it was called via?

Comment: Also - having slept on it, I see what you mean about the URL prefix being in the top-level urls.py. In this particular case, the frontpage app provides (tada!) the front page (^$) URL, so I can't, but I will for the others. Good advice.

Comment: @AnotherHowie Sorry, I misunderstood what it was you were trying to do. I've actually never done this, but I'll update my answer with a possible solution using the top level namespace to nest your URLs.

Comment: I think I confused everyone including myself by using the same string for the namespace as the appname... I see what you mean now! I still think it's strange that the reusable app (that may not even be yours) gets to dictate the namespace to its host, but at least the template part makes sense :-)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone to reference.

This worked for me, Django 2.2.2

```
# project urls.py
# DjpollsConfig is my app config
from djpolls.apps import DjpollsConfig
djpolls_app_name = DjpollsConfig.name

urlpatterns = [
    path(djpolls_app_name, include('djpolls.urls', namespace='djpolls_app_name'))
]
```

```
# app urls.py
from django_proj.urls import djpolls_app_name
app_name = djpolls_app_name
```

```
# app template
{% url 'djpolls_app_name:detail' question.id %}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: What's really cool is that now you don't even need to add the namespace keyword argument if the app_name is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(r'', include('noc.apps.frontpage.urls', namespace = 'abc')),
```

and then in your templates:

```
{% url 'abc:frontpage:front_page_edit_page' slug=page.slug %}
```

Comment: This has the same problem though: what is the benefit? There's now a prefix that is hardcoded in the template, and has to match one in the code. That's where I was when we started, but without a colon.